# Safari 5.0 Button spacing

Tags: html, css, xhtml, button, safari

I am busy with the buttons in a website. In Chrome, IE, Firefox all the buttons look nice and good but in Safari 5.0 there is a strange spacing.

See here a screenshot:

[image]

The css:

```
button{
    background-image : url(../gfx/forms-btn-l.gif);
    background-position : left top;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-color : transparent;
    border : none;
    outline: none;
    padding : 0 0 0 13px;
    margin : 0 ;
    cursor : pointer;
    overflow: visible;
    width : auto;
    height : 30px;
}

span{
    float : left;
    background-image : url(../gfx/forms-btn-r.gif);
    background-position : right top;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-color : transparent;
    overflow : hidden;
    padding : 0 13px 0 0;
    margin : 0;
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : 12px;
    font-weight : bold;
    line-height : 2.44em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #d75700;
    color : #FFFFFF;
    white-space : nowrap;
    height : 30px;
}
```

The HTML:
`<button type="submit"><span>Zwart</span></button>`

How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net with a direct url to the images so that we can manipulate it?

Comment: I have edit the html and put a div around de span and then i get it working :)

Comment: You should put your solution down below and then mark it as accepted then, for other people who come across this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css:

```
button{
    background : none;
    border : none;
    outline: none;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0 4px 0 0;
    cursor : pointer;
    overflow: visible;
    height : 30px;
}

button div {
    background-image : url(../gfx/forms-btn-l.gif);
    background-position : left top;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-color : transparent;
    border : none;
    outline: none;
    padding : 0 0 0 13px;
    margin : 0 ;
    cursor : pointer;
    overflow: visible;
    width : auto;
    height : 30px;
}

span{
    float : left;
    background-image : url(../gfx/forms-btn-r.gif);
    background-position : right top;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-color : transparent;
    overflow : hidden;
    padding : 0 13px 0 0;
    margin : 0;
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : 12px;
    font-weight : bold;
    line-height : 2.44em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #d75700;
    color : #FFFFFF;
    white-space : nowrap;
    height : 30px;
}
```

The HTML:
`<button type="submit"><div><span>Zwart</span></div></button>`